# Gmail Logout/Redirection via YouTube

Tags: google-account

When Signing out from Gmail, I am redirected to various other Google/Gmail pages and then finally to the main page. The flow goes like this:

1. First [Link](https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?service=mail&continue=https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service%3Dmail%26passive%3Dtrue%26rm%3Dfalse%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F%253Fui%253Dhtml%2526zy%253Dl%26bsv%3Dllya694le36z%26ss%3D1%26scc%3D1%26ltmpl%3Ddefault%26ltmplcache%3D2%26hl%3Den%26from%3Dlogout&hl=en)
2. Second [Link](http://www.google.co.in/accounts/Logout2?hl=en&service=mail&ilo=1&ils=s.IN%2Cs.youtube&ilc=0&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FServiceLogin%3Fservice%3Dmail%26passive%3Dtrue%26rm%3Dfalse%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F%253Fui%253Dhtml%2526zy%253Dl%26bsv%3Dllya694le36z%26ss%3D1%26scc%3D1%26ltmpl%3Ddefault%26ltmplcache%3D2%26hl%3Den%26from%3Dlogout&zx=-1611560991)
3. Third [Link](http://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/Logout2?hl=en&service=mail&ilo=1&ils=s.youtube&ilc=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FServiceLogin%3Fservice%3Dmail%26passive%3Dtrue%26rm%3Dfalse%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F%253Fui%253Dhtml%2526zy%253Dl%26bsv%3Dllya694le36z%26ss%3D1%26scc%3D1%26ltmpl%3Ddefault%26ltmplcache%3D2%26hl%3Den%26from%3Dlogout&zx=2102648178)

And then finally the main page appears.

What may be the possible reason for Google doing so?

Also the third link in the redirection flow points to YouTube, which is blocked in my college. So I can never logout from my account successfully in college.

Is there any way to avoid/skip this and what may be the possible intention for such kind of redirection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you sign out of your Google Account, they want to make sure that they sign you out of all your Google services. Therefore they have this flow to ensure that you get logged out of google.

Your domain admin can whitelist accounts.youtube.com, which will stop you from seeing the error while allowing your network to continue blocking videos. You could also, according to some sources, try a different browser.

Comment: note that there is a useful version of the third link if you *want* to log out of just YouTube, but not Gmail: (https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/Logout2?hl=tr&service=mail&ilo=1&ils=s.youtube%2Cs.TR&ilc=0)[https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/Logout2?hl=tr&service=mail&ilo=1&ils=s.youtube%2Cs.TR&ilc=0]